# How to get AWS service Catalog Provisioned Product's Envet Output section details through AWS Cli

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-powershell, aws-service-catalog

Actually Service Catalog is using CloudFormation template for provisioning the Products/environments.

I tried Provisioning the product with help of AWS document example. In that AWS is having CF template for Creating AWS Instance with public access.

I Provisioned the Product(I mean created the EC2 Instance) but here I need the IP address of EC2 instance which is created through Cloudformation.

Could anyone help me with the AWS Cli command/AWS Powershell command to get the output section of the Product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer myself.
Finally I got the IP address of Provisioned Product.

```
$newProduct = New-SCProvisionedProduct -ProvisionedProductName $productName -ProductId $productId -ProvisioningArtifactId $artifactId -ProvisionToken testToken -ProvisioningParameter @( @{key="KeyName";value="test"} )
$envInfo = Get-SCRecord -Id $newProduct.RecordId
$envIP = $envInfo.RecordOutputs[1].OutputValue
Write-Host $envIP
```